# using $index to compare values returned by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an array object of size 2. I am doing ng-repeat on the array object and displaying the values. But now I want to also compare the values inside the object. Can i use $index for that ?

I tried using $index, $index-1 but it is not working. Infact it won't display any value at all.

```
div.timeline-block(ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.alertHistoryData | groupBy: 'historyDateWithoutTime' | toArray:true | orderBy: 'historyDateWithoutTime':true " )
        h2.timeline-block-header
            | {{ value[0].historyDateWithoutTime | date: "mediumDate" }}
        ul.timeline-entry-list
            //- to make the array of data render in reverse order we add "true" to orderBy filter
            li.timeline-entry-list-item(ng-repeat= "history in value | orderBy: 'alert-modified-date':true")
                h3.list-item-time
                    | {{ history["alert-modified-date"] | date:"mediumTime"}}
                div.list-item-content
                    div.label-block.label-block-horz
                        | State
                        div.label-block-value
                            | {{ history.state[$index] | alertState }}
                        hr.hr-default.hr-spacer-sm
                        div.label-block-value
                            | {{ history[$index-1].state }}
                    div.label-block.label-block-horz
                        | Priority:
                        div.label-block-value
                            span.label-priority(ng-class="'priority-{{history.priority}}'")
                                | {{ history.priority}}
```

Is it because I am using filter also? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history` is a item in `value`.

Change:

```
history[$index-1].state
```

To:

```
value[$index-1].state
```

Comment: that worked :)  thank you so much.Can you explain what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: Ex: `value` = [{state: 'a'}, {state: 'b'},{state: 'c'}]. Use `ng-repeat="history in value`, we have  first `history` is {state: 'a'}. You can't select to hisory[$index].state.